# Modified microwave oven transformer makes fuses blow upon powering without load

Tags: fuses

I have a microwave oven transformer (MOT) from an old microwave that I want to use as a step down transformer. Unfortunately, I destroyed the primary coil when removing it so I made myself a new primary coil but it has ~50 turn instead of the original 200. The new wire is also thicker. I didn't put a secondary coil yet (so no load.) There is only the primary coil inside the transformer.

Upon powering at 230V AC, the fuses of my house blow immediately.

Any idea on what to do as I would like to use the transformer as a power transformer later?

Would connecting the secondary coil to a load change something? I am sure that making a new primary with a thinner wire with more turns would help but I would have to buy it and wait a whole lot so it would be great if that can be bypassed.

Comment: That's not going to work. Get another microwave oven transformer, you're just throwing good coil wire after bad lol. It helps your control to use hand tools not power tools.  Transformer design is not for amateurs, it's out of the depth of most people here honestly.   (though you can't go too far wrong replacing the high voltage secondary with *a few* turns of very heavy wire e.g. for a spot welder low-voltage high-current source).  DO NOT work in very high voltage such as is used for fractal wood burning, an art technique used to make Darwin Awards.

Answer (score 2):

Do not work this way! You don't want to be attaching any experimental transformers directly to mains without testing them first. At least get an isolation transformer to reduce the risk of electrocution somewhat, a variac to smoothly bring up the voltage while observing the load current, and some means of measuring and limiting the current without blowing any fuses/tripping house breakers.

An incandescent light bulb in series with the load is a current indicator - the brighter it's lit, the more current the load consumes, generally speaking. The bulb also limits the current, so you need a switch to bypass it for normal operation. It's better to have an analog current meter in series though - one with an easy-to-see pointer.

You can learn more about that by searching for "current limiting variac isolation transformer", for example. The term is a mish-mash of separate devices, but that's how people often refer to it: it's really a separate current limiter, a separate variac, and a separate isolation transformer, hooked together to make for a versatile bench tool.

Winding any transformer to operate reliably from mains will require lots of care not only for basic functionality but for longevity and electrical safety  - you would want to learn a bit about transformer design first. Even if just from YouTube videos - and no, the ones where they just wind it and "hook it up" are **not** what you want to follow.

*Microwave oven transformers have left a **trail of dead experimenters' bodies behind them***. They are lousy general-purpose transformers anyway. They are designed to drive the anode of a vacuum tube, and that's what they are usable for. Even for that job, they are cost-optimized a lot, so they don't perform as well as they otherwise could.

It's not a bad idea to experiment hands-on with transformers - just don't connect them directly to mains, and learn some theory behind transformer design, so you can at least know whether something has any chance of working at all. Other answers cover that in detail.

Answer (score 1):

If it did have 200 turns of wire originally, then it can't work with 50 and will blow fuses. You need 200 turns of wire.

Answer (score 1):

> *I made myself a new primary coil but it has ~50 turn instead of the
> original 200*

So, you went from 200 turns on the primary to 50 turns.

The reactance of the magnetization inductance (a component parallel to the applied AC supply) would reduce by the square of the turns reduction i.e. the modified magnetization inductance will be 16 times smaller. If the primary previously took a couple of amps, the modified primary will take 32 amps.

> *Would connecting the secondary coil to a load change something?*

Things would not improve.

Comment: 2A is far too little for a microwave, more realistically it'd be 8 amps (yes, I'm thinking 230V) and that would mean 128A.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica That is assuming the core did not just immediately saturate! MOTS run stupid amounts of magnetising current even in normal use, and typically have magnetic shunts to raise the leakage inductance as well, they are NOT normal transformers (And even with a normal one you couldn't drop the primary inductance 16 times without either reducing the primary voltage 4 times or raising the frequency (And you cannot raise the frequency because the core material is not suitable).